# AngularJS different size and value select boxes in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, select, angularjs-ng-repeat

I know where the issue is, but so far my attempts to solve the problem were not successful. Any help is appreciated.

I am creating a table from JSON data in an ng-repeat loop. One of the table columns represents select boxes, which are of different values and sizes. This select statement is inside the ng-repeat block.

```
               <tr ng-repeat="unit in unitsData">
                    <td>{{unit.unitName}}</td>
                    <td>{{unit.unitType}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <select class="form-control" ng-model="unit.unit" ng-options="option.value as option.name  for option in getUnitListForUnitType(unit.unitType)"></select>
                    </td>
               </tr>
```

I am getting this error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!

Based on Angular documentation for select boxes, the problem comes from   getUnitListForUnitType function, which I created in the controller to return different lists based on the provided parameter. Not sure how this code could be corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the ng-repeat gets reevaluted for each item, which then itself calls the digest cycle again, which is the error you are getting.

Instead of calling:

```
getUnitListForUnitType(unit.unitType)
```

You need to somehow have a $scope variable, for example:

```
... ng-repeat ... option in unitList[unit.unitType]
```

where you have a $scope variable called $scope.unitList that is a list of lists. When you setup your class just initialize that list of lists to a variable and that should to the trick.

```
$scope.unitList = {
    unit1 : ['item1', 'item2'],
    unit2 : ['item3', 'item4']
};
```

Comment: This is great, let me try to replace the function with a variable, a list of lists.

Comment: All worked fine, no errors showing anymore. Appreciate your time and help.

Comment: Glad I could help!